# Jwt Bearer Authentication middleware always sets User.Identity.IsAuthenticated to false

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, owin-middleware

I've added `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` middleware to my application to Authenticate all incoming requests:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{

    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    #region Autofac config

    var container =AutofacWebapiConfig.Initialize(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    #endregion
    #region RoutConfig

    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    #endregion

    //Register middlewares
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new MyJwtAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.Use<ReadBodyMiddleware>();
    app.UseWebApi(config);

}
```

And this is my MyJwtAuthenticationOptions class:

```
public class MyJwtAuthenticationOptions: JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    public MyJwtAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        var secretkey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretKey"].ToString();

        AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active;
        AuthenticationType = "Basic";
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretkey)),
            ValidAlgorithms = new string[] { SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature }
        };
    }
}
```

Now let's see how token is generated:

```
public static string GenerateToken(string userid)
{
    var expireMin = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenExpirationMinutes"].ToString();
    var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretKey"].ToString();

    byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(secretKey);
    SymmetricSecurityKey securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
    var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
              new Claim("UserId", userid)}, "Basic"),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(expireMin)),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey,
        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    JwtSecurityToken token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(descriptor);
    return handler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

But when i put generated token inside `Authorization` header and send it to server via `Postman`

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false
```

Authorization header is correctly in `Bearer` format
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your controller or method have the `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: no...it doesn't...Authentication middleware should set IsAuthenticated  to true if its a valid token.

Comment: Do you have documentation for that?

Comment: Then what is the point of using 'UseJwtBearerAuthentication' middleware?

Comment: it's responsible for authenticating, authorization is not my case currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was originated from two points:

****point1**:**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Owin auth
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    // Web API routes
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0,
     new SimpleModelBinderProvider(typeof(DocumentModel), new FromFormDataBinding()));
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

this line was not same as other points of my api that i used `Signature`

```
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

Changed to this:

```
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter("Signature"));
```

**point2:**

Inside `GenerateTokebn` class i was reading secretkey in this way:

```
byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(secretKey);
```

changed to this line to be same as `MyJwtAuthenticationOptions` class:

```
byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
```